# Geolocation with elasticsearch using placenames (geocoding)

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, geolocation, geocoding

I'm using elasticsearch to search items and now I want to be able to search my cities and towns in a given country.

I've loaded an SQL database up with the following information (here is example data).

```
Name: London
Type: City
Long: 51.234
Lat: 32.123
Country: UK
```

A few questions about this:

1. Can I load this into elasticsearch to turn it into a geocoder.
2. Will this mean search location search needs two queries, one to geocode and then one to search with the co-ordinates
3. Are there any plugins that I should be using instead where I can use my own data.

Comment: Have you read up on elasticsearch's geospatial types (see [geo point](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html) and [geo shape](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-shape-type.html)) and search filters (see [geo distance](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html) and [geo polygon](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-polygon-filter.html))?

Comment: That's all great but is based on supplying elasticsearch with the co-ordinates. I'm talking about converting my towns, cities, etc to co-ordinates without using a third party service

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [Pelias](https://github.com/pelias/pelias). It's an Open source geocoder based on ElasticSearch

Comment: You can try Pelias as a hosted service called Mapzen Search: https://mapzen.com/projects/search/ Developer keys with generous rate limits are available for free.